# Docker Multi Host (Swarm) Persistence Storage

Tags: docker, storage, docker-swarm

I am running Docker in swarm mode with below version

```
Client:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:41:23 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:42:49 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Experimental: false
```

To achieve Persistence storage in native container or host based we can mount host drive, But if the host is down data will be lost because its not shared.

Another option can be using NFS setup and mounting volume in container, But this will lead another problem of Slowness and if NFS Server is down everything is down.

Do we have any other Highly Available,Secure solution to setup persistence storage with Multi Host sharing.